# NGINX: How to return inline html?

Tags: nginx

I want to achieve something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        return 200 <html><body>Hello World</body></html>
    }
}
```

i.e., any request should return the inline html. Is this possible with NGINX?

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        return 200 '<html><body>Hello World</body></html>'
    }
}
```

But testing in browser did not render the html, instead the browser tried to download a file containing the html which is not the behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the return directive to return HTML code. Remember to set proper content type, otherwise the browser will asume raw text and won’t render the code:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        add_header Content-Type text/html;

        return 200 '<html><body>Hello World</body></html>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try that but testing in browser did not render the html, instead browser tried to download a file containing the html. Any suggestion what the issue might be?

Comment: The content type header was missing. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: How to return it only for home page and not any path?

Comment: No matter what I try, it keeps outputting the string verbatim, not as html. Any ideas? I am trying to use <b> or at least <br> tags

Answer (score 2):

just setting the content type header seems to work on some browsers, however safari on ios stil tries to download the file.

You might have set the content type somwhere else, resulting in 2 content type headers this way.

e.g. in my case curl showed me:

```
< date: Thu, 11 Nov 2021 01:00:06 GMT
< content-type: application/octet-stream
< content-length: 49
< content-type: text/html
```

The fix is to clear the global type and set one for a given url

```
 server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        types {}
        default_type text/html;

        return 200 '<html><body>Hello World</body></html>';
    }
}
```

Comment: No matter what I try, it keeps outputting the string verbatim, not as html. Any ideas? I am trying to use <b> or at least <br> tags

Comment: @slav what do your headers look like? Try posting the output of curl -v <url>